# Unity 2D: Timer in while loop not working, loop stays forever

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my boost work by starting at 0 when the game starts.

In my game I can pick up boost coins to fill up my booster canister.

```
public static int boost;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherObject)
{
    if (otherObject.tag == "Boost")
    {
        boost++;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlaySound(BoostSound, 5.7F);
        Destroy(otherObject.gameObject);
    }
}
```

After the player picks up enough boost coins to use the booster in the 2d vehicle.

you need a minimum of 3 boost to start booster. Each booster coin is equal to 1 second of boost.

I just want the player to be able to use the booster if they have over 3 boost coins collected, if they have 3 or more than that represents how many seconds they can use the boost for.

Button call code

```
public void BoostButton()
{
  StartCoroutine("Use_VehicleBoost");
}
```

Booster code that a button calls.

```
IEnumerator Use_VehicleBoost()
{
    //   Check which boost package player picked
    int boostLevel = SecurePlayerPrefs.GetInt("BoostLevel");
    if (boostLevel == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Boost Level: None");
        yield return null;
    }
    else if (boostLevel == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Boost Level: 1");

        float aceleRate = 400, maxFWD = -2500;
        while (Player.boost >= 3)
        {
            vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().accelerationRate += aceleRate;
            vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().maxFwdSpeed += maxFWD;

            //  Meant to slowly take one point/ Time second away from boost tank
            Player.boost = Player.boost - Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Player.boost <= 0)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Problem: code stuck inside while loop so Unity freezes. It can never escape the loop but how if Im calling --boost using deltaTime while the loop running.

Comment: `yield return null` is supposed to be in the `while` loop block. Right now, it's not. You have it outside the `while` loop and inside the `if` statement.

Comment: This is what I missed thanks. Why couldnt the while loop break without the yield return null?

Comment: Because `Player.boost >= 3` is always true. It has to be false for the loop to break. Now, if you are changing `Player.boost` inside the `while` loop to false, it would have worked. If you are changing `Player.boost` inside **another** script, it wouldn't work because other scripts will never get the change to run due your `while` loop. When you add `yield return null` to it, it will tell Unity to wait every frame at the end of the `while` loop. While waiting every frame, other scripts can now run therefore your `Player.boost` will get the chance to be changed.....

Comment: ah so `yield return null` is what holds it back publicly. So `Player.boost` is not counting down, how would the `Player.boost - Time.deltaTime` in the while loop count down? Is it not holding value by holding to the frame?

Comment: Your're not changing `Player.boost` in that loop so the while loop keeps running forever as long as `while (Player.boost >= 3)` is true. That's what caused the freezing. `Player.boost` is not `PlayerScripts.boost`. To change it has to be `Player.boost = somethingMoreOrEqualsTo3`.

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be `Player.boost` instead of `PlayerScripts.boost` in the code, I updated it. So I cant do `boost = boost - deltaTime`? If i make `boost = something` then i cant count down the boost by time use.

Comment: You can as long as long as it makes boost to be < 3.  Note that `Time.deltaTime` is time since last frame. It doesn't make sense to use it without `yield return null`. If you use it in `while` loop without `yield return null`, you will keep getting value of last  frame and the the `while` loop will only run in one frame. For example, if you expect the boost to change value over time slowly, it won't happen. It will in one frame. This means that `Time.deltaTime` will have one value. If the first value of `Time.deltaTime` in the `while` loop is 0, it will always be 0 until the loop exist.

Comment: All your scripts run one after another, not in parallel (even Update and everything else). Simply put Unity executes all your code one after another then advances one frame and does your code again. So until the loop finishes Unity(and everything else) is kinda on "pause", when its done Unity advances one frame. What "yield return null" does is basically telling Unity to "finish"/"exit" this method and resume it from the next line on the next frame. As it is now you remove deltaTime(rounded to 0) from boost over and over without allowing Unity to continue with the rest of the code and frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that while loop to check, use it into IEnumerator and wait every frame. Eg:

```
IEnumerator Use_VehicleBoost(){
...
while (Player.boost >= 3)
{
     yield return null;
}
...
}
```

Comment: still same problem, I updated the question with `Coroutine` like you mentioned.

Comment: if you use Coroutine, Unity cant freeze with this code you show.

Comment: it does freeze, maybe because it's still stuck in the while loop

Comment: Because you didn't increase your variable Player.boost >= 3. Just double check your variable when it can pass 3.

Comment: i’m not trying to increase Player.boost .Player collects seconds to be used as boost until 0.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by setting a bool in update to flip true when the ability is activated, and flip false once the conditions are no longer met. A method is also called when that bool flips true that holds the desired behavior. I was actually having the same issue as you  and didn't realize yield return null was the solution, so this is what I came up with.

```
    if (ultCharge >= pilotUltMin && !pilotUlting && !pilotUltingPressed)
    {
        if (Input.GetButton(bumperR1))
        {
            pilotUltingPressed = true;
            pilotUlting = true;
            curCharge = ultCharge;
            pilotUltingPressed = false;
        }
    }

    if (pilotUlting)
    {
        PilotUlt();
    }
}

private void PilotUlt()
{
    if (ultCharge > curCharge - pilotUltMax && ultCharge >= 0)
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.up * SwitchController.ShipSpeed * 1.5f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        ultCharge -= 0.7f;
        ultExhaust1.SetActive(true);
        ultExhaust2.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        pilotUlting = false;
        ultExhaust1.SetActive(false);
        ultExhaust2.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```